# Parse User Password Reset Swift iOS

Tags: swift, parse-platform, passwords, reset, parse-server

I have a Swift 2 iOS app that uses Parse as a backend. I am trying to add a feature that allows the user to reset their password, but I don't want the user to have to get a reset-password-email (like the default function is in Parse for password reset).

Is there a function I can call, or some code I can use to just edit the Parse Password Object in the User Class? I did some research and saw some things about Cloud Code, but wasn't able to get anything working. Is that a good solution? Or is there a better one?

Comment: This question is duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490228/how-to-change-pfuser-password-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28506863/2060508) approach to change password of parse account without sending email.